# facebook website login with app not doing login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am just newbie to facebook app and I am doing a simple login in a page from facebook SDK with application id.

I have created the app in facebook. After that my facebook code something looks like this

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
     appId      : '619422074760339', // App ID
     channelURL : '', // Channel File, not required so leave empty
     status     : true, // check login status
     cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
     xfbml      : false  // parse XFBML
   });
};
```

I have given the appId and secret key.  When I tried to login from my localhost using this script it showed me error like

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this issue. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The server your app is running on doesn't have the same URL as you have given in the Facebook Apps Setting.

Please check both the URL's , they have to be same.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and I found that there was a mismatch in my "redirect_uri" and "Valid OAuth redirect URIs".

In my code, I had set:

```
redirect_uri = "http://www.mywebsite.com/validate.php";
```

But in my Facebook app I had set Valid OAuth redirect URIs (in Settings):

```
http://website.com/validate.php
```

All I was missing "www". So I changed Valid OAuth redirect URI in my Facebook app to following:

```
http://www.website.com/validate.php
```

I worked like a magic for me.
Hope it will help you.